# Set IsDropDownOpen for multiple ComboBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a List of `ViewModels`. The List contains a `LabelViewModel` and `ComboBoxViewModel` and displays them in a `View`. Basically when the View is showing up both ComboBoxes should be opened. I tried to use the `IsDropDownOpen` property. The first box gonna open, but the dropdown disappear really quick and only the second box stays open. Seems like he cant decide which one to be opened.

Thats my ViewModel:

```
 public class WortAuswahlCollectionViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs> AuswahlChanged;
    public WortAuswahlCollectionViewModel(List<UniqueString> wortAuswahl)
    {
        if (wortAuswahl != null)
        {
            WortAuswahlCollection = new ObservableCollection<UniqueString>(wortAuswahl);

            if (WortAuswahlCollection[0].Value.Length > WortAuswahlCollection[1].Value.Length)
            {
                ComboBoxSize = WortAuswahlCollection[0].Value.Length * 28;

                MaxComboBoxSize = ComboBoxSize * 10;
            }
            else
            {
                ComboBoxSize = WortAuswahlCollection[1].Value.Length * 28;

                MaxComboBoxSize = ComboBoxSize * 10;
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<UniqueString> m_wortAuswahlCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<UniqueString> WortAuswahlCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return m_wortAuswahlCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_wortAuswahlCollection != value)
            {
                m_wortAuswahlCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private int m_comboBoxSize;
    public int ComboBoxSize
    {
        get
        {
            return m_comboBoxSize;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_comboBoxSize != value)
            {
                m_comboBoxSize = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private int m_maxComboBoxSize;
    public int MaxComboBoxSize
    {
        get
        {
            return m_maxComboBoxSize;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_maxComboBoxSize != value)
            {
                m_maxComboBoxSize = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding WortAuswahlCollection}" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilledComboBox}" MinWidth="{Binding ComboBoxSize}" MaxWidth="{Binding MaxComboBoxSize}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= Value}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't open two ComboBox controls at the same time. The internal Popup control captures the mouse when it opens and thus will automatically close when another ComboBox opens.

Comment: Is there no way to bind it? i mean these comboboxes are 2 viewmodels